# Linking correctly to a file with a question mark

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am looking to restore an old site and have to maintain links like they were before. Some of the links have question marks in their URL's. I need some help in getting them link correctly.

I have recreated the situation I'm facing with a simple example.

```
<a href="four?get.php">Link four</a>
```

The file is four?get.php

I have tried linking using,

```
<a href="four%3Fget.php ">Link four</a>
```

but it did not work.
P.S. I'm testing it on an Apache server.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "*I need some help in getting them link correctly.*" — Define "*correctly*".

Comment: That's because there's a PHP file associated with it, using a GET method; most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a web *file* with a question mark in its name, since question marks have a specific role in [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)s - they are prefixing the *query strings* part of URL.

If you really have a static file with a `?` in its name (which is *wrong* and unlikely), I would suggest making a (hard) link to it (e.g. with [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) command, on the web server):

```
  ln -s 'four?get.php' four-question-get.php
```

in the appropriate directory (perhaps under `/var/www/`) and then use

```
  <a href="four-question-get.php">Link four</a>
```

But I would think that your link `<a href="four?get.php">Link four</a>` really is to an URL with some query string, and you should investigate what `four` is (probably some active URL handed by some PHP code) and what are the query strings it is expecting.